# How can I set Photoshop default unit for free transfom?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, units

You can easily set default units in Photoshop preferences, but they doesn't seem to have any effect on free transform (⌘T on the Mac), which always start with percentage as unit.

I'm aware that you can change units with a right click on the text, but it will be back to percent when you restart Photoshop.

Is it possible to change this behaviour? Can I have it automatically set to pixel from the start?

Comment: If you are about to type in the size, you could just write e.g. "256 px" into the box without first selecting the unit with right click. (Though, if you'd want to use the slider or mouse wheel, this won't help)

Comment: Similar with me, I also tied to find the way, but with no success. Very often I need to measure the size of objects and each time I restart Photoshop the units change back to %, which is not useful at all for me. I thought there could be some configuration file that I could edit, but I couldn't find anything like that. Anyway thank you for the right-click trick - helps a bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid not, I've scanned the Adobe Forums AND the preferences of Photoshop itself some time ago because it's (quite rightly) irritating. I think it is just as the software works. I know you can change the units in the preference menu, but it doesn't seem to affect this.